# jQuery Parent Class Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a slide up affect with jQuery to a DIV when a link inside of the DIV is clicked, but the problem i am running into is the class of the DIV's are defined by a loop. So, i can't define the DIV class in the jQuery line, because each DIV class is different and i cannot determine ahead of time what they are. I am trying to use .parent and .child but I am not sure how to go about this. Is this making any sense?

Comment: no, this makes no sense. provide some code

Comment: Not much, but I think I get the drift.  Can you post some example HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the click of the element you want (in this case I just used a simple anchor element). Then find the first parent that is a `div` and perform the `slideUp()` effect.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('div:first').slideUp();
});
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/XNnSp/

Comment: Your selector has an extra space, it should be just `div:first`, or it'll fail in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

### Two (most obvious) ways

**FIRST**
If your tree is always defined in terms of depth you could access your parent DIV doing just that:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().slideUp();
```

**SECOND**
Add an additional class that doesn't clash with dynamic ones and do this:

```
$(this).closest(".some-custom-class").slideUp();
```

Comment: You want `".some-custom-class"` since `$("selector").closest` takes a selector argument rather than a class argument.

Comment: This actually wouldn't work for me the way i have everything set up. Sorry i wasn;t more specific in the description. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if that's what you are looking for http://jsbin.com/ehoza3

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
});
```

Comment: If the link is the direct child of something other than a DIV this will not have the desired effect. Example: <div><p><a>link</a></p></div>. Here the <p> and <a> elements will be removed yet the <div> will remain.

Comment: This actually didn't work for me. The whole page is wrapped in a DIV and it was sliding everything up. Sorry i wasn't more specific. Thankyou.

Comment: @tinifni, this solution is for "add a slide up affect with jQuery to a DIV when a link inside of the DIV is clicked", I didn't find any `p` tags in the problem description.